# Flatten simple list

Tags: list-manipulation

I know this is probably a very silly question but I am trying to get {x,y,z,p} to be x,y,z,p.

For this I am using `Flatten` in this way:

```
Flatten[{x, y,z,p}]
Flatten @@@ {x, y,z,p}
```

but it does not work. How can I do this?

**NOTE:** What I want to do is the following:

Give a list such as:

```
list={36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107};
```

I want to add four numbers (30.40.50,60) into the 4 position such:

```
Insert[List, Flatten[{30, 40, 50, 60}], 4]
```

The problem I am having is that these numbers are not flatten and I get: `{36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, {30, 40, 50,  60}, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107}`

Comment: Have a look at `Sequence`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what I also tried `Sequence [x,y,z,p]` but this does not work either

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is the `FullForm` of the thing you want to convert `List[x,y,z,p]`into? @b.gates.you.know.what has already suggested using `Sequence` which is very useful when you want to splice elements into a `List` or an argument list without changing the structure.  But everything in Mathematica is an expression, and it's not clear what kind of expression you want to convert your list into.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have updated the question to include exactly what I want and the full form of what I want to convert

Comment: Well the easy answer is simply to move the `Flatten` outside the `Insert`, but I expect that isn't what you want, is it?

Comment: You can insert the sub-list first and then use Flatten[list,1].

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

list1 = {36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107};

list2 = {30, 40, 50, 60};
```

There are many ways to do what you want; for example,

```
res[1] = Insert[list1, list2, 4] // Flatten

(* {36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, 30, 40, 50, 60, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107} *)

res[2] = Join[list1[[1 ;; 3]], list2, list1[[4 ;;]]];

res[3] = {list1[[1 ;; 3]], list2, list1[[4 ;;]]} // Flatten;

res[4] = Insert[list1, $a, 4] /. $a :> Sequence @@ list2;

res[5] = Insert[list1, Inactive[Sequence] @@ list2, 4] // Activate;

res[6] = Insert[list1, Hold[Sequence @@ list2], 4] // ReleaseHold;

res[7] = Insert[list1, Splice[list2], 
  4]; (* Splice is experimental and is new in v12.1 *)

res[8] = Catenate[{list1[[1 ;; 3]], list2, list1[[4 ;;]]}];
```

All produce identical results

```
SameQ @@ (res /@ Range[8])

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use `FlattenAt` with the same position argument as that of `Insert`:

```
FlattenAt[Insert[list, {30, 40, 50, 60}, 4], 4]
(* {36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, 30, 40, 50, 60, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Riffle[list,#,{4,4+Length[#],1}]&[lst2]

 (* {36.3019, 36.9458, 37.983, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 38.9583, 39.2301, 40.0107} *)
```